# LCD's delays with precise timer interrupts

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc, atmelstudio

I'm developing a system that allows to set a square wave period, then, once setted, it drives a led with a square wave with the setted period.
Anyway if i set the period, the output square wave isn't consistent, with heavy random period variation.

I'm using a standard CTC timer because i need multiple output, so i can't use one single pwm output. I'm also using a piece of code that i use often, so i'm sure that this piece of code works well.

```html
if(oldtack!=tack)
{
    oldtack=tack;
       
 if((oldtack%(period/2))==0)
 {
  PORTB^=((1<<PORTB0)|(1<<PORTB1)|(1<<PORTB2)|(1<<PORTB3)|(1<<PORTB4)|(1<<PORTB5));
 }
}
```

This above is the code that i often use, already tested and quite sure that works.

The only thing that is different from my usual code is the LCD.

I'm using an I2C LCD display with a library that i found in internet. I'm afraid that this LCD and its library is affecting the precision of the period of my system, that i need as precise as possible.

Can you help me?

Here the whole code: https://pastebin.com/J6zCzcqi

EDIT
I'm using this library: https://davidegironi.blogspot.com/2013/06/an-avr-atmega-library-for-hd44780-based.html

Comment: At the top you say you are driving an LED and later on you say it's a LCD. Are you attempting to service that under interrupt from the timer? There is a [page here](http://maxembedded.com/2011/07/avr-timers-ctc-mode/) about using CTC mode timers.

Comment: Nope. I'm using the LCD to build a user interface, but the system drive the LEDs. I'm worried that this LCD with its library affect the precision of the square wave period. Scrolling the library i saw many delay(); can this cause this issue?

Comment: What can cause this issue is servicing the LCD under interrupt, since its code contains delays. On the other hand, you may be polling the timer (not reponding to an interrupt) and the same may still happen, because of the time taken to service the LCD. There isn't enough code to know.

Comment: In the first post there is my whole code plus the site where i took the library.
There is a way to prioritize the timer's interrupts?

Comment: Sorry I don't explore 3rd party code sites, only code posted in the question.

Comment: In your source, the code you brought in the question, actually placed not in the interrupt but in the main code, after a lot of "lcd_" commands. So, of course, it will be executed in arbitrary moments of time. So, either move software PWM into the interrupts or use a hardware PWM. Also, the code looks so strange. `((oldtack%(periodotutte/2))==0)` - what is that? Why you need a remainder calculation for each cycle? This expression will not give you constant frequency anyway.

Comment: Do not be offended, but code is IMO horrible. It does not have any chance to work properly. The long as a spaghetti main loop, buttons in pin interrupts, timer interrupts which do nothing. Completely wrong approach. There is nothing to improve - bin it, reconsider the program and write it from the beginning

Comment: Why do you need a precise timer interrupt?  what is the reason of the led?  Are you sure you need subhundredt of second, for example?